# Неправильная кодировка в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Записывал данные в бд, русские символы как обычно превращались в "кракозябру". 
Дописал строчку

```
 mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

получилось

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "2") or die (mysql_error ());
 mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); 


    // Выбрать БД
    mysql_select_db("user") or die(mysql_error());
```

текст записывается гуд но отображается "кракозябрами"

Поменял на `mysql_query('SET NAMES cp1251');`

Наоборот, читается нормально записывается не правильно. 
Сравнение кодировки в БД менял на соответствующие.
В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Так вы сделайте кодировку на сайте UTF-8 и все будет нормально и вноситься и читаться.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду на пхп файле?

Comment: слишком мало информации чтобы дать точный ответ, но все элементы должны быть в одной кодировке: HTML страницы, тексты в PHP-скрипте, работа с бд.

Comment: У меня только пхп файл, без хтмл, и он в нужной кодировке

Comment: Ну а откуда вы данные берете чтобы внести их в БД? и где у вас отображается плохо?

Comment: в пхп файле. У меня гет запрос заносит данные в бд, и этот же файл выводит занесенные данные

Comment: у вас HTML генерируется в PHP-файле, вот HTML должна быть в UTF-8 кодировке. http://htmlbook.ru/html/meta/http-equiv

Comment: Хорошо,  я понял в какую сторону двигаться, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В PHP файле `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`,
а также кодировку самого файла измените.